# Git Custom diff text converter not being called

Tags: git

**Goal**: For specific binary files i want "git diff" to use our custom tool i can't get this to work. https://github.com/go-gitea/gitea/issues/12288 was the closet help i could find. My debug shows the custom tool not being run. Example:

git diff --textconv ABCProduct\Setup\Projects\Example\GERMAN.dbf

**Environment**: Visual Studio on Windows in use but script doing the checks runs in the git repository root. The current branch can have changed DBF files.

**Details**: We wrote a simple checksum program that outputs a textual SHR256 based on the offset provided, e.g. "checksumsha256 -from 4 " provides a checksum skipping the first 4 bytes. In this case we are comparing DBF files which have a timestamp in the first 4 bytes then the rest is content. So DBFs (binary file) with the same content can have different SHR256 however when the tool is used, they both return the same checksum. When the content changes in the DBF, you get different checksums with the tool and you know they are different. Example output to stdout:

SHA256: 5A53C82726589E6CAB87579900535BC1B9828DAE4897F04676140FFDC1DBE2DC

So what i did was add "***.dbf diff=dbfsha256**" to .**gitattributes** then in the **.git\config** file added

```
[diff "dbfsha256"]
textconv = Build/CheckSumSHA256.exe -from 4
prompt = false
```

I tried this with addition of $1 in the textconv line I saw in a post somewhere as well. I am assuming that local .git\config takes priority over c:\users<user>.gitconfig (i tried updating both with no success). We where hoping to use this approach to other binary files which may contain non important header info.

Thanks

Comment: The `textconv` value cannot be a command line, AFAICS; it must be just the program name. To test that, drop the arguments `-from 4`. Is the converter then executed?

Comment: I think you *can* have arguments in the `textconv` driver definition (contrary to @j6t's suggestion) but it's definitely worth trying without them. I think the more important thing is to avoid relative-path commands like `Build/ChecksumSHA256.exe` as you don't necessarily know what the current working directory is at the time the textconv filter is started. Instead, *install* the conversion program so that any program anywhere can run it without a path, and then just list `textconv = CheckSumSHA256` (perhaps with arguments, perhaps without).

Comment: Thanks, i tied all combinations here and could not get a result. Originally added --textconv just to ensure there was not some global override running. I placed the utility in the path   and also gave it a full url. I know the .git/config was being read as i deliberately placed an error in it. I tied no "-from 4" which means the whole file is looked at. Procmon confirms it is not being run.

Comment: OK problem solved, the issue was case. Somehow the test file case differed from the path git had, and git produces no error if the path is incorrect! As i am on windows.
So my original settings where correct. The key point is the "git status" path must match the disk path. Also the case setting https://git-scm.com/docs/git-config/2.14.6#Documentation/git-config.txt-coreignoreCase only seem to affect .gitattributes  So with set to true, only the *.dbf entry is needed whether the file is .DBF or .dbf on disk.
So do we leave this post as is as as a guide for this ?

Answer (score 0):

The solution i proposed does work however it did not work during testing because  the path used to the variable had the wrong case partially.
Take out - Even on Windows git is case sensitive for the path to files in the branch (even when $core.ignoreCase set true) $core.ignoreCase seems to only apply to references in the .gitattributes file.